# RxJava and saving data in collections

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java, reactive-programming

after some coding with rxjava which makes you think in a totally different way i still cannot understand what should i do when i want some operation to save some data in a collection (lets say a map of key value) for me to approach later on after all requests are done.
for example lets say i want to emit some put calls to some api and save all failed calls response in a map to later on do some "mistake correction".
till now it looks like i need to write the whole flow from top to bottom to do this request -> mistake -> correct which is a pipe of operations, i want to separate to two different operations which happened in different times.
I do realize i'm probably missing a key concept with rxjava.

in conclusion how do i cache data outside in a collection for later on to address?  is just putting data in a concurrentHashMap when the request failed is good idea/practice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to add a side-effect to an RX chain, you'd want to use [doOnNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext-rx.functions.Action1-) or [doOnError](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnError-rx.functions.Action1-) - probably the second for your use case. You can add it to your collection inside the `Action1` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I see several questions here.

- Changing state from Rx is indeed called side-effect and is normally done via *.doOn...()* methods.
- Handling both successful and erroneous events in one method is done by applying *.materialize()* operator.
- Keeping state in a concurrentHashMap is possible, but then you will not get any notifications that it is updated.
- So I would probably rather keep state in an object that is updated via *.scan()* applied to your materialized response stream.
- Combining all responses into one stream without re-subscribing can be done with *.switchLatest()/.switchOnNext()* operator. See RxSwift example here - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift/blob/master/RaspSwift/RaspAggregator.swift ('.switchLatest()' in RxSwift is the same as '.switchOnNext()' in RxJava)